# Grid height problems

Tags: css

I can't seem to be able to control the height of my rows efficiently. I've set 1fr for 6 columns which has remedied the problem of the rows resizing when the height of the page increases. But now the footer height increases along with the page height. This happens in small screen sizes. Around 400px in width. How can I fix this? Thanks.

```css
    /* The CDN */

    /* @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo'); */
    html, body {
     width: 100%;
     height:100%;
    }

    @font-face {
     font-family:Exo;
     src:url(exo/Exo-Regular.ttf);
    }
    * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     font-family:Exo;
    }

    .header {grid-area: header;}
    .main {grid-area: main;}
    .footer {grid-area: footer;}

    body {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-areas:
     'header header header header header header'
     'main main main main main main'
     'footer footer footer footer footer footer';
     grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
     margin: 0;
     text-align: center;
     grid-gap: 10px;
    }

    a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: black;
    }

    /* header */

    header {
     grid-column: 1 / span 6;
     grid-row: 1;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     align-content: center;
     border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    } 

    h1 {
     font-size: 17px;
     font-weight: normal;
     margin: 0;
    }

    /***********************************/

    main {
     display: grid;
     grid-column: 1 / span 6;
     grid-row: 2;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    }

    .searchbar {
     grid-column: 1 / span 6;
     grid-row: 1;
     padding: 10px;
    }

    .searchinput {
     border: 1px solid black;
    }

    input.icon[type="search"] {
     width:100%;
     height:20px;
     box-sizing:border-box;
     border:2px solid #ccc;
     border: radius 4px;
     font-size:16px;
     background-color:white;
     background-image:url('/libs/fontawesome-free-5.4.1-web/svgs/solid/search.svg');
     background-size:15px 15px;
     background-position:10px center;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     padding:12px 20px 12px 40px;
    }

    .thestuff {
     grid-column: 2 / span 4;
     grid-row: 2;
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid black;
     padding: 2px 16px;
    }

    .thestuff img {
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 100%;
    }













    /* footer */

    footer {
     display:grid;  
     grid-column: 1 / span 6;
     grid-row: 3;
     align-content: center;
     height:60px;
     border-top: 1px solid black;
     bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Guzo Lemine</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Get the cdn of all the necessary non-local files after completion -->
    
    <!-- Font Awesome CDN -->

    <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    -->
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
    
    <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    -->

    <!-- Libraries -->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="libs/fontawesome-free-5.4.1-web/css/all.css" />
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <header class="header">
        <h1><a href="#">Guzo Lemine</a></h1>
    </header>

    <main class="main">
        <section class="searchbar">
        <form method="GET" action="">
            <input class="searchinput icon" type="search" name="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
        </form>
    </section>
        <section class="thestuff">
            <img src="img/s-l500.jpg" alt="F-150 Raptor">
        </section>
    </main>

    <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2018 Guzo Lemine. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </footer>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Found the solution. By changing the grid-template-rows to auto 1fr auto; it works.